# Getting value from List<object>

Tags: c#

I need to get a single value  from my list  and pass it as a paramater

```
List<object> selectedValues;
private void GetSelectedValues() 
{

    ASPxGridView grid = (ASPxGridView)StoreDropDown.FindControl("StoreGV");
    List<string> fieldNames = new List<string>();
    foreach (GridViewColumn column in grid.Columns)
        if(column is GridViewDataColumn)
            fieldNames.Add(((GridViewDataColumn)column).FieldName);
    selectedValues = grid.GetSelectedFieldValues(fieldNames.ToArray());

}
```

Here is part of my my method

```
store = Store.SelectOne(270);//Here is where I want to get value from GetSelectedValues
                             //Insted of 270 I want the vaue from GetSelectedValues  

if (e.Date < leadDay || e.Date > OrderDOW.OrderOutDate ||!store.IsAvailable(e.Date))
{


    e.Cell.Attributes["disabled"] = "disable";
    e.Cell.Attributes["style"] = "pointer-events: none; background-color: red";

}
```

Comment: Your question is rather ambiguous, try to explain it better.

Comment: GetSelectedValues doesn't return anything yet.  What are you expecting from this function exactly?

Comment: Which single value? What if the list contains multiple values?

Answer (score 0):

I thing i understood your question, you can use a foreach to do whatever you want with each list elements

```
foreach(String fieldName in fieldNames)
{
    store = Store.SelectOne(fieldName);

    if (e.Date < leadDay || e.Date > OrderDOW.OrderOutDate ||!store.IsAvailable(e.Date))
    {
        e.Cell.Attributes["disabled"] = "disable";
        e.Cell.Attributes["style"] = "pointer-events: none; background-color: red";

    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I only need the value from the first column.  I probably don't need a List. The way I have it now it puts all values from each column in a list.